# Get response type in HTTP request in Angular

Tags: angular

I have this function that gets a `blob` from a server via http (to download a file):

```
getBlob(data: any) { 
    return this.http.post("theurl", data, 
             {observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob'} ).
        pipe(
          map(response => response)
        );
}
```

Problem is that the server may return a `blob`, or if the user is not authorized (or other application errors) it will return a `json` with the error message and error code.

If the HTTP response type is a `blob`, I will store the `blob` response as a downloaded file. If the HTTP response type is `json`, I will take the error code and message and show to the user.

How to adjust this function to receive either a `blob` or a `json` response type? How to get the contents of the `json` response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
            response => {
                if (response.body.type == 'application/json') {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function(){
                        const parsed: any = JSON.parse(reader.result as string);
                        processJson(parsed);
                    };
                    reader.readAsText(response.body);
                }
                else 
                    processBlob(response.body);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends a bit on the server. But first. This function/method is not returning blob nor json. It returns an observable, because this is how angular works. When you are not logged in, your server should respond with an error code you can intercept in catch method.

```
return this.http.post(
  'theurl',
  data,
  {observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob'}
)
.pipe(
  map(response => response)
);
.catch((err) => {
  // Do messaging and error handling here
  return Observable.throw(err)
});
```

And in component you do something like this:

```
this.myService.myMethod(data).subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(res);
  // some success logic
},
(err) => {
  console.log(err);
  // some errorlogic
});
```

You could also try to check for specific keys from JSON you would receive from http call to check if its JSON or not. However i wouldn't recommend this solution.

Comment: I tried to analyze the response, when is json it returns the type but not the message itself.

Comment: A this point i am not exactly sure what are you trying to achieve. However have you tried simple if statement to check if response is blob? if (MyBlob instanceof Blob) { // code }

However your error (not auth) logic should be handled as i described in my comment where you console.log(err). The "err" is your server response that should be JSON with your message.

Answer (score 0):

First console the response you will get to know response using using that you can throw message.

```
   getBlob(data: any) { 
        return this.http.post("theurl", data, 
                 {observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob'} ).
            pipe(
              map(response => response)
            );
        console.log(data)
      if (data['blob'] === 'true'){
       alert("Authorized User")
    }
   else{
      alert("Unauthorized User")
      console.log(data['message']);
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing what you described, but the json could have a "not authorized" or "invalid file type" message. I need to be able to analyze the json.

Comment: You will get response message from server. you can print that in console where you can analyze response according to that, you can print or alert user throw direct response received from server.

Comment: Let me know if you not cleared, will create stackblitz

Comment: I tried to debug in the console the response, if the type is json I only see  the value `application/json` in `response.body.type`. If you can create a stackblitz it will be great.

Comment: Sorry am not getting exactly what problem you have facing, if you are only concern about authorisation you can use http response code to allow the user to do actions.

Comment: I cannot use the response code, as the server may send multiple error codes and error messages. The authorization was only one example. I need to get a JSON (including error code and error message) or a BLOB (the file to download).

Comment: Please explain me bit more what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: Please see my answer, I needed to process blob or json as response.